# how solr filter large set of ids

Tags: solr, filter, facet, large-data

I got two tables, one is news, the other is contact.

news: newsid, news_content, news_orgid

contact: contactid, contact_orgid

I indexed these two tables in solr, so i have two cores.
but i have a use case that i need to find out all contactids by news_content.
I get a large set of orgids from news index first, approximate 1 million. I want to use it as a filter query in solr to search, like

> select?q=*:*&fq=id:100+id:101+id:102+id:103+id:104

but solr has a limit of 1024 boolean queries. So i can't transfer in one process. Is there another ways to fix this?

Because i want to use solr's facet data, i can't search all data in solr and compare with the ids.

Appreciate your help!

Best Regards! Rick.

Comment: you can change the max boolean queries value in the configuration but 1 million is too much !!!!!!!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Jayendra. If i change the max boolean queries value, it may cause fatal performance issues. As you say, 1 million is too much, may be solr can't hanle this kind of problem.

Comment: yup 1 million is far too much. Whats the use case ??? you can still do it in batches but it is gonna take time.

Comment: yeah, the use case is something like this, I have two cores, one is news, the other is people, each news and people have a organ id. I want to design a advance search, filter by people job-level and news content. So i first search news and get a huge set of organ ids, then i need to put these ids in people search.                  PS:I took your advice, changing the max boolean queries value to 10K, it takes about 2s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem with solr4.0 new feature: join. First i put contact and news in one core, as http://searchhub.org/2011/02/12/solr-powered-isfdb-part-4/ , then we can join with orgids

Comment: Today i found out that solr4 supports cross-core join，so i don't need to change the index structure, that's brilliant!